# How do I parse JSON in Go?

Tags: json, go

#### JSON

```
{
  "id" : "12387",
  "inv" :[
    {
      "qty" : 5,
          
       "seq" : 2,
       "invIs" : "1HG9876",
       "addCharges" :[
         {
          "amnt" : 24,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          },
          {
          "amnt" : 24,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          }
        ],

      "seq" : 3

    },
    {
      "qty" : 5,
          
       "seq" : 2,
       "invIs" : "1HG9876",
       "addCharges" :[
         {
          "amnt" : 24,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          },
          {
          "amnt" : 24,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          }
        ],

      "seq" : 3

    }
  ],
    "charges" : {
      "fee" : 24 ,
      "bkg" : 7676
    }

}
```

My JSON structure is like that shown above. I need to take **amnt** in `inv-addCharges`
in an array. If it has ten elements in the array, I need to get that in an array containing the particular `amnt` alone in such a way like

```
[{"amnt" : 34 } ,{"amnt" : 34} .... so on ]
```

**Things I tried:**

```
var j map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(ticket), &j)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Pull out the parents object
    bytInv := j["inv"].([]interface{})    

    // // Print out mother and father
    fmt.Println(bytInv)
```

**Output**

```
[map[qty:5 seq:3 invIs:1HG9876 addCharges:[map[amnt:24 char:REI type:MT] map[amnt:24 char:REI type:MT]]] map[qty:5 seq:3 invIs:1HG9876 addCharges:[map[amnt:24 char:REI type:MT] map[amnt:24 char:REI type:MT]]]]
```

After this, I was not able to proceed any further.

*Note:* I don't want to use structs because I have many JSON structures for this. And that's my requirement given.

Comment: to proceed you just need to repeat what you did down the tree, casting each node to its real type. After doing this for a few minutes you'll understand why you _do want_ to use structs :) trust me.

Comment: can you please give some sample code ? i didn't gt how to cast each node. ?

Comment: Your question title is "How to parse json in Go".

If you don't want to use a type system, then you shouldn't be using Go. Use structs to (safely!!) Unmarshall your data into. That's idiomatic Go, which is a type safe language. Take advantage of that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requirement or not, I really don't see why you insist on not using structs for this. 
Can you elaborate on exactly why this is the case?

As evidenced by the example program below, the solution is so much easier to understand and reason about if you just represent the data as properly typed structs. You can run it on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DZnLB_i7jM) to see it in action.

There is one part of your JSON data which confuses me. Each Item node contains the `seq` field twice. Both with a different value. Which ever way you use to interpret the data, one of the fields will be lost. Depending on the implementation of the unmarshaller, it will either ignore the second field, or overwrite the first one with the second value. This is a bug in the way your data is generated.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    charges, err := findCharges()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, c := range charges {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    }
}

// findCharges locates all 'AddCharge` instances and returns them in a slice.
func findCharges() ([]AddCharge, error) {
    var prod Product

    data := []byte(jsonString)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &prod)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var charges []AddCharge

    for _, item := range prod.Items {
        charges = append(charges, item.AddCharges...)
    }

    return charges, nil
}

type Product struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Items []Item `json:"inv"`
}

type Item struct {
    Quantity   int         `json:"qty"`
    Sequence   int         `json:"seq"`
    Inventory  string      `json:"invIs"`
    AddCharges []AddCharge `json:"addCharges"`
    Charges    []Charge    `json:"charges"`
}

type Charge struct {
    Fee int `json:"fee"`
    Bkg int `json:"bkg"`
}

type AddCharge struct {
    Amount int    `json:"amnt"`
    Char   string `json:"char"`
    Type   string `json:"type"`
}

const jsonString = `{
  "id" : "12387",
  "inv" :[
    {
      "qty" : 5,
       "seq" : 2,
       "invIs" : "1HG9876",
       "addCharges" :[
         {
          "amnt" : 24,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          },
          {
          "amnt" : 12,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          }
        ],

      "seq" : 3

    },
    {
      "qty" : 5,

       "seq" : 2,
       "invIs" : "1HG9876",
       "addCharges" :[
         {
          "amnt" : 64,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          },
          {
          "amnt" : 36,
          "char" : "REI",
          "type" : "MT"
          }
        ],

      "seq" : 3

    }
  ],
    "charges" : {
      "fee" : 24 ,
      "bkg" : 7676
    }

}`
```

**edit**: If the `addCharges` data is really all you are interested in, you can omit all the fields you do not need from the structs. The unmarshaller will simply ignore the data for which the struct has no field defined.